# Multiple joins of the same dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I am composing a complex query in T-SQL. The dataset I have is a single table (let's call it `Table T`), and the data look like

```
| Happened                | Contributor | Status | Direction | Purchased |
|-------------------------|-------------|--------|-----------|-----------|
| 2014-10-06 01:00:00.000 | A           | 0      | NULL      | NULL      |
| 2014-10-06 02:00:00.000 | A           | 1      | NULL      | NULL      |
| 2014-10-06 03:00:00.000 | A           | 2      | inbound   | NULL      |
| 2014-10-06 04:00:00.000 | A           | 0      | NULL      | yes       |
| 2014-10-06 05:00:00.000 | A           | 2      | outbound  | yes       |
| 2014-10-06 06:00:00.000 | B           | 2      | inbound   | NULL      |
```

So I have

- a unique pair of date (`T.Happened`) and a subject who caused an event (`T.Contributor`);
- status at the moment of the event happened;
- some direction, which can be either inbound or outbound (boolean-ish column);
- some purchase mark (same as previous).

What I need is a query that, for each distinct contributor, selects

- earliest datetime when status has changed from 0 to 1;
- earliest datetime when status was not 0 and `T.Direction = 'inbound'`;
- count of events when `T.Purchased = 'yes'` and status is not 0.

and displays the whole set of contributors even if other fields in the row are empty.

What I tried were multiple joins, just like

```
...
FROM Table T
JOIN Table T2 ON
    (T.Contributor = T2.Contributor
    AND T.Happened < T2.Happened
    AND T2.Status = 1
    AND T1.Status = 0)
JOIN Table T3 ON
...
```

The result dataset I'm after should look like

```
| Contributor | StatusChangedFrom0To1   | StatusWasNot0AndDirectionWasInbound | StatusWasNot0AndPuchasedWasYes |
|-------------|-------------------------|-------------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| A           | 2014-10-06 02:00:00.000 | 2014-10-06 03:00:00.000             | 2014-10-06 05:00:00.000        |
| B           | NULL                    | 2014-10-06 06:00:00.000             | NULL                           |
```

What approach should I follow and what direction should I dig to get the result desired? Should I use certain type of join (e.g. full outer join)?

I use MS SQL Server 2008, and I'm tied to this version for, you know, "enterprise and stuff" reason, so upgrade to any newer version is unlikely.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that the statuses only increase, then the earliest time the status changed from 0 to 1 is the earliest time the status is 1 (this is true of the sample data in your question):

```
select contributor,
       min(case when status = 1 then happened end) as StatusChangedFrom0To1,
       min(case when status <> 0 and direction = 'inbound' then happened end) as StatusWasNot0AndDirectionWasInbound,
       min(case when status <> 0 and purchased = 'yes' then happened end) as StatusWasNot0AndPuchasedWasYes,
       sum(case when status <> 0 and purchased = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from table t
group by contributor;
```

If the assumption for `StatusChangedFrom0To1` is not true, the query is still possible as a conditional aggregation, but it will require additional work to get this variable.  In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()` for this purpose:

```
select contributor,
       min(case when status = 1 and prevstatus = 0 then happened end) as StatusChangedFrom0To1,
       min(case when status <> 0 and direction = 'inbound' then happened end) as StatusWasNot0AndDirectionWasInbound,
       min(case when status <> 0 and purchased = 'yes' then happened end) as StatusWasNot0AndPuchasedWasYes,
       sum(case when status <> 0 and purchased = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from (select t.*, lag(status) over (partition by Contributor order by happened) as prevstatus
      from table t
     ) t
group by contributor;
```

In earlier versions, I would use a correlated subquery for equivalent functionality.

EDIT:

The correlated subquery looks like:

```
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 t2.status
              from table t2
              where t.contributor = t2.contributor and t2.happened < t.happened
              order by t2.happened desc
             ) as prevstatus
      from table t
     ) t
```

Comment: At MSDN, LAG() function reference says, "Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the use of a self-join in SQL Server 2014." But what if I constrained to MS SQL Server 2008? Should I then actually use join to compose table with additional faux columns or should I rather take a deeper look at `select ... from (select ...)`?

Comment: That's right, on my server, `LAG()` didn't work. I'm glad you provided a subquery solution. It helped a lot, thank you!